# How to I deal with exception in asp.net core api with mediatR?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, mediatr, mediator

I'm new at MediatR and wondering if It's good to make a try catch in every endpoint in all api controllers to catch if the mediatR throw an error ?

like when the user register if the password was weak the mediatR throw an Exception (manually thrown) and then catch it in the controller and return BadRequest or what

or trying to get a user with id don't exists and so on...

I can make a global Response Class the has IsSuccess prop and an IEnumerable<string> which represent the errors if there

```
public class Response<T> where T : class
{
    public T? Result { get; set; } = null;
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string>? Errors { get; set; }
}
```

and then every query or command will return Response<The_Actual_Response_Type>